# How do I use a custom log for my rake tasks in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, logging

I have a rake task that calls functions like this:

```
namespace :blah do
    task :hello_world => :environment do
       logger.info("Hello World")
       helloworld2
    end
end

def helloworld2
   logger.info("Hello Again, World")
end
```

I want the log output to a custom log, and I really don't want to have to pass a log reference every time I make a function call.  I found this somewhere (can't find it again):

```
def logger
  @@logger ||= Logger.new("#{RAILS_HOME}/log/blah.log")
end
```

But this does not work for me and I am not sure what it even does because I grabbed the code a long time ago and haven't used it until now.  I can't search for @@ on google (tried +"@@" rails) to see what it does.  Any help on this issue would be great.  I am hoping for a quick solution and not having to install a gem or plugin (unless there is a really really good reason to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

rake disables logging in production mode. make sure you're running in development mode if you want it to log

Answer (score 0):

1. What do you mean by "does not work for me"? I just tried this same code and it worked - created a new log file and put some text in it.
2. @@logger is a class variable, it's a language issue, not Rails' one. I believe there's no need in further explanations :)
3. You've probably mistaken typing "function helloworld2" :)

Comment: function was a mistake.  maybe it's a path issue.  when i say doesn't work, i mean nothing gets written to the log file. i have a "puts 'hello world'" and a "logger.info('hello world')" in consecutive lines.  I see the puts, but not the logger

Comment: Ah, put RAILS_ROOT instead of RAILS_HOME

Comment: strange...this still is not working and the path is definitely right.  this EXACT code works for you?

Comment: Except that I have RAILS_ROOT, not RAILS_HOME. I created a new .rake file in my lib/tasks folder, the contents are below. I'm running it with Rails 2.3.2, and both strings are properly output. Honestly, I have no idea why this can't work.

namespace :blah do
    task :hello_world => :environment do
       logger.info("Hello World")
       helloworld2
    end
end

def helloworld2
   logger.info("Hello Again, World")
end

def logger
  @@logger ||= Logger.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/log/blah.log")
end

Comment: try that with 2 different tasks and 2 different log files.  i think that is where my problem lies.  the first task i created writes to its log file fine but then the second task i created writes to the first task's log file.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Rails Recipes Recipe 84 from @topfunky shows how to define a custom logger. He has some code in the environment config file (production would look like this): `RAILS_ROOT/config/environments/production.rb`:

`config.logger = RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new(config.log_path)`

I'd test that out instead of redefining the class variable as you have. He might have something on http://nubyonrails.com to check as well.

Comment: where do you define config.log_path? how is config.logger defined? why are you setting it to RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER? Thanks