# Rails: How to write to a custom log file from within a rake task in production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, rake, web-crawler

I'm trying to write to my log files while running a rake task. It works fine in development mode, but as soon as I switch to the production environment, nothing is written to the log files.

I read here

[How do I use a custom log for my rake tasks in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022093/how-do-i-use-a-custom-log-for-my-rake-tasks-in-ruby-on-rails/1648159#1648159)

that this is the normal behavior and also found a #wontfix ticket in lighthouse.

My question: Is there a way to output, what's going on while my rake task is running? It performs some crawling and runs for hours. I would prefer if the output went in a specific log file like /log/crawler.log

Right now I'm just using this command to write to the log files:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.info "Log Text"
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: I run my rake tasks in PRODUCTION mode in a similar scenario.

Answer (score 15):

The problem you are having is that rails ignores 'info' level logs in production mode.

I'd recommend reading this: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/classes/Logger.html

and creating your own logger:

```
logger = Logger.new('logfile.log')
logger.info "Something happened"
```

Comment: I took this approach. It is working in Development and staging environment. But logging to logfile.log is not happening in production environment. log_level of both staging and production environments is 1 - Logger::INFO

Answer (score 3):

You can make a new logger with Logger.new("file.log") and then call it's methods like this.

```
  task :import_stuff => :environment do
    require 'csv'
    l = Logger.new("stuff.log")
    csv_file = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/stuff.csv"
    CSV.open(csv_file, 'r') do |row|
      l.info row[1]
     end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to write out the buffer where you need it:

```
logger.flush
```

or you can turn on auto flushing:

```
task :foo => :environment do
  Rails.logger.auto_flushing = 1
  Rails.logger.info "bar"
end
```